# Format output of concatenating 2 variables in unix

Tags: unix

I am coding a simple shell script that checks the space of the target path and the space utilization per directory on that target path (example, I am checking space of /path1/home, and also checks how all the folders on /path1/home is consuming the total space.) My question is regarding the output it produces, it is not that pleasing to the eye (uneven spacing). See sample output lines below.

```
SIZE USER_FOLDER DATE_LAST_MODIFIED
83G FOLDER 1 Apr 15 03:45
34G FOLDER 10 Mar 9 05:02
26G FOLDER 11 Mar 29 13:01
8.2G FOLDER 100 Apr 1 09:42
1.8G FOLDER 101 Apr 11 13:50
1.3G FOLDER 110 Feb 16 09:30
```

I just want the output format to be in line with the header so it will look neat because I will use it as a report. Here is the code I am using for this part.

```
ls -1 | grep -v "lost+found" |grep -v "email_body.tmp" > $v_path/Users.tmp 
for user in `cat $v_path/Users.tmp | grep -v "Users.tmp"` 
do
    folder_size=`du -sh $user 2>/dev/null` # should be run using a more privileged user so that other folders can be read (2>/dev/null was used to discard error messages i.e. "du: cannot read directory `./marcnad/.gnupg': Permission denied")
    folder_date=`ls -ltr | tr -s " " | cut -f6,7,8,9, -d" " | grep -w $user | cut -f1,2,3, -d" "`
    folder_size="$folder_size               $folder_date"
    echo $folder_size >> $v_path/Users_Usage.tmp 
done

echo "Summary of $v_path Disk Space Utilization per folder." >> email_body.tmp 
echo "" >> email_body.tmp 
echo "SIZE USER_FOLDER DATE_LAST_MODIFIED" >> email_body.tmp

for i in T G M K
do
    cat $v_path/Users_Usage.tmp | grep [0-9]$i | sort -nr -k 1  >> $v_path/email_body.tmp 
done
```

Thanks!
EDIT: Formatting

Comment: please use the same formatting tool (`{}`) for sample data as you have used for your code. Easier to visualize data with fixed width type ;-) `grep '[0-9]'"$i" $v_path/Users_Usage.tmp | ...` is more efficient (`cat` is redundant when std-in/std-out is in use).  Good luck.

Comment: Hi thank you for suggesting the fixed width, for others I used printf '\ %-Xs \n' $txt. where x is the width of column and $txt is the symbol to be printed.

Comment: I'm not clear, is the report at the top now in its current formatting? and you want the data to align with the column headers? I will be away most of today. Likely others will help with your improved problem description. But rather than reply to my Qs here, see if you can make your Q follow the form of "I have this data, I want it to look like X, but is is looking like Y, and I am using this code, what am I doing wrong?". Plus1 for sample data and having tried to solve your problem! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

When you print the data use printf instead of echo

```
cat $v_path/Users_Usage.tmp | while read a b c d e f
do
    printf '%-5s%-7%s%-4s%-4s%-3s-6s' $a $b $c $d $e $f
done
```

See [here](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/cgi-bin/manpage?3%20printf)